# Can css a class on the same element affect another classe's behaviour?

Tags: css

class on the same div

```
<div class"myClass1 myClass2">
```

Can `myClass1` behave like this

```
.myClass1 .myClass2 {background:#ff0000}
```

in css?

Comment: If you mean only affect elements with both classes, yes, just make sure they are "connected" so nice whitespace inbetween: `.myClass1.myClass2` instead of `.myClass1 .myClass2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate classes like this, `.myClass1.myClass2`, leaving out the gap in between. It's not a cascade in your case.

I do believe there are issues in older browsers when doing this, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use (multiple) as many classes as you wish but syntax is without any spaces:

```
.myClass1.myClass2 {background:#ff0000}
```

Answer (score 1):

They can overwrite behavior.

In you example you have actually specified a child selector.

e.g

```
.myClass1 .myClass2 {background:#ff0000}
```

Would effect the div `myClass2` if nested in `myClass1`

```
<div class"myClass1"> 
    <div class"myClass2"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

What you want is

```
.myClass1.myClass2 {background:#ff0000}
```

Which would work with

```
<div class"myClass1 myClass2"> 
</div>
```

This is the basis of how OOCSS works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wright,.myClass1.myClass2 {background:#ff0000}
this will apply to those elements having both of this class.

Answer (score 0):

This will affect classes as following
    .myClass1 .myClass2 {background:#ff0000}

```
<div class="myClass1">
     <div class="myClass1">
     </div>
</div>
```

myClass1 will only be affected by such elements

```
.myClass1{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely clear what you’re asking, but if you want to style an element based on whether it has two specific classes on it, you can do so like this:

```
.myClass1.myClass2 {
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

This will give all elements that have a class of `myClass1` *and* a class of `myClass1` a red background, e.g.

```
<div class="myClass1">This won’t have a red background.</div>

<div class="myClass2">This won’t have a red background.</div>

<div class="myClass1 myClass2">This will have a red background.</div>

<div class="myClass1 myClass2 myClass3">This will have a red background.</div>
```